# PHP character problem

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have a problem with characters in PHP, I call date from MySQL that holds some special characters for example: (œÏïÎîÔôËÊÉÈëêéèÀàçÍíóÓéèÉÈÚúáàÁÀãñÑÖöÜüßÉ) the result give me � how can I fix that ?

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue - is your DB capable of holding the proper characters within the charset?

Comment: http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet

Answer (score 0):

That character means you're outputting ANSI characters while telling the browser it is UTF-8. You should correct your HTML ContentType meta and/or content-encoding header, or convert the characters to UTF8 using utf8encode first.

Comment: I wrote a few tips on how to fix character encoding that might help at http://www.simonrjones.net/2010/06/falling-foul-special-characters/